# Multi selection select box is automatically selected when it is populate the data. how to prevent that?

Tags: php, html

I have created select box with multi selection option. I have a problem, when the dropdown box populate data, all are selected, how to prevent that.

```
 <?php
                $query = "SELECT est_id,sec_plan_number,plot_plan_number,plot_code,land_extent
                          FROM tbl_plot where sec_plan_number = '$_POST[slt_planno]' and isactive=1 `enter code here`
                          order by abs(plot_plan_number)";

                $selectbox ='<select name=plot_no[] style="width: 240px; height:150px" multiple >';
                $selectbox.= "<option value=0><label style='background-color:yellow;'>Select Plots With Same extent</label></option>";
                foreach ($db->query($query) as $row) 
                {           
                     $id=$row['plot_code'];
                     $ppno=$row['plot_code'];
                     $landext=$row['land_extent'];
                     if($row[id] == $_POST[officer_name]){$isSelected = ' selected="selected"';} 
                     else {$isSelected = '';}
                     $selectbox.= "<option value=".$id.$isSelected.">".'&nbsp&nbsp'.$ppno.'-----'.$landext.'&nbsp'.'Perch'."</option>";
                }
                     $selectbox.='</select>';
                     echo $selectbox;
            ?>
```

this is the selectbox. it is automatically select when loading, that makes my validation false

[image: selectbox]

Comment: have you checked is it come in else condition or not?

Comment: Might be a typo but ... $_POST[officer_name] should be  $_POST['officer_name']

Comment: can you please provide select box html??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in your if condition
`if($row[id] == $_POST[officer_name]){$isSelected = ' selected="selected"';}`

`$row[id]` and `$row[officer_name]` not only are missing quotes (`$row['id']`), but both keys do not exist, you only select these columns from DB: **est_id,sec_plan_number,plot_plan_number,plot_code,land_extent**

therefore - even if you added the quotes - your if statements checks `if(null == null)`, which is **always true!**. So every option gets the selected="selected".

On a side note, I assumed the `enter code here` in your sql query was a copy paste error for that question. ;)

Comment: i removed all "selected" string from the entire code. now my problem solved. thanks @Cashbee.